# Back up single huge table in SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a 200 GB file in an Azure SQL database. I want to back this file up to free up some space. I can't do a BCP out - since this is also the realtime database. I am approaching the 1TB limit, hence I need to do this soon.

How do I proceed? Note: this is SQL Azure, not SQL on-prem.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to pipe the data out from this table into some other form of cloud storage. I don't want to drop the table. I don't want to delete the data permanently.

Comment: What means a 200 GB file? Does the complete database take up that space? Or ist there a table containing many blobs/files which take up most of the space? Has the export to be transactional?

Comment: I'm confused as well - SQL Database Service hides the notion of *files* - it's just a database. Are you just talking about your content in general nearing 1TB?

Comment: You can find which tables in your sqldb take up the most space and how much. This table takes 200 gb.

Comment: you could simply backup the database and truncate/delete the said table

Comment: SQL Database has well-documented procedures for backup. But if you want to reduce a table's size, that's going to be up to you to decide what to export, and then what to remove.

Comment: Read my question closely, guys. My content is nearing 1 TB. This is my production db - I can't jump bcp out a 200gb table which by itself will take forever and impact production load.